# How to draw axes inside an ellipsoid

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

I would like to draw the axes showing dimensions a, b and c inside an ellipsoid:

```
a=12.4786;
b=33.3395;
c=21.0691;
Q=RegionPlot3D[##,Mesh->15]&[x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+(z-c)^2/c^2\[LessSlantEqual]1,{x,-15,15},{y,-40,40},{z,0,45},PlotStyle->Directive[Black,Opacity[0.01]]]
```

It could also be something similar to the following image found on the internet. Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = 12.4786;
b = 33.3395;
c = 21.0691;
e1 = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, 0}, {a, b, c}];
c1 = RegionCentroid[e1];

axes = Graphics3D[{
   Arrowheads[0.04]
   
   , {Red, Arrow[Tube[{c1, a UnitVector[3, 1]}, 0.2]]
    , Text[Style["x", Bold, 14], a UnitVector[3, 1] + {2, 0, 0}]
    , Text[Style["a", Black, 12], (a/2) UnitVector[3, 1]]
    , {Black, Dashed, 
     InfiniteLine[{-UnitVector[3, 1], UnitVector[3, 1]}]}
    }
   
   , {Blue, Arrow[Tube[{c1, b UnitVector[3, 2]}, 0.2]
     ]
    , Text[Style["y", Bold, 14], b UnitVector[3, 2] + {0, 2, 0}]}
   , Text[Style["b", Black, 12], (b/2) UnitVector[3, 2]]
   , {Black, Dashed, 
    InfiniteLine[{-UnitVector[3, 2], UnitVector[3, 2]}]}
   
   , {Darker@Green, Arrow[Tube[{c1, c UnitVector[3, 3]}, 0.2]]
    , Text[Style["z", Bold, 14], c UnitVector[3, 3] + {0, 0, 2}]
    , Text[Style["c", Black, 12], (c/2) UnitVector[3, 3]]
    , {Black, Dashed, 
     InfiniteLine[{-UnitVector[3, 3], UnitVector[3, 3]}]}
    }
   
   , {Black, AbsolutePointSize[6], Point@c1}
   }
  , Boxed -> False
  ];

g3 = SliceContourPlot3D[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2
  , "CenterPlanes"
  , {x, y, z} \[Element] e1
  , Contours -> 0
  , BoxRatios -> Automatic
  , ContourStyle -> Thin
  , ContourShading -> {Opacity[0.4, White]}
  , SphericalRegion -> True
  , Boxed -> True
  , Axes -> True
  , AxesEdge -> {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}, {-1, 1}}
  ];

Show[g3
 , Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2], e1}]
 , axes
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate it! How can I give an outer Mesh to this as shown in the question? @Syed

Comment: It shows three ellipses along xy, yz, xz planes as shown in the OP figure. You will have to superimpose a `RegionPlot3D` (with `Mesh` option) as shown by Daniel Huber. A crowded 3D plot does not promote understanding though as human brain is easily tricked by the viewing perspective. If you replot my answer without the `axes` it will become almost useless.

Comment: I want to retain the `axes` as well as the ellipses. Maybe the ellipses can be made darker and the Outer Mesh with less number of meshes. How can I incorporate the `RegionPlot3D` (with `Mesh` option)?

Comment: A possibility: `RegionPlot3D[x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + z^2/c^2 <= 1
 , {x, -15, 15}, {y, -35, 35}, {z, -25, 25}
 , BoxRatios -> Automatic
 , Mesh -> {0, 4, 0}
 , MeshStyle -> Thick
 , PlotStyle -> {Opacity[0.3, White]}
 ]`. You can use mesh in the `x` and `z` directions as well.

Comment: Yes, this works perfectly! Thank you so much @Syed

Comment: Just a doubt. When I change the center of the ellipsoid to (0,0,d) in `e1` and take `x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + (z - d)^2/c^2` where `d= 21.0691` in `g3`, the arrows X and Y are going outside the ellipsoid. I don't understand why. @Syed

Comment: I have assumed that the center is at `{0,0,0}` and used `{a,b,c}` as axes lengths to generate the graphics/text for `axes`. You can modify this solution to suit your needs.

Comment: But the code you provided doesn't answer my initial question. Could you please modify this for an ellipsoid with center `(c1,c2,c3)=(0,0,c)`? @Syed

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
a = 12.4786;
b = 33.3395;
c = 21.0691;
Q = Show[
  RegionPlot3D[##, Mesh -> 5] &[
   x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + (z - c)^2/c^2 \[LessSlantEqual] 1, {x, -15, 
    15}, {y, -40, 40}, {z, 0, 45}, 
   PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Opacity[0.01]], 
   BoxRatios -> Automatic -> 1],
  Graphics3D[{Green, Thickness[0.01], 
    Line[{{{-a, 0, c}, {a, 0, 20}}, {{0, -b, c}, {0, b, c}}, {{0, 0, 
        0}, {0, 0, 2. c}}}], Red, Text["a", {8, 4, 1.1 c}], 
    Text["b", {1, 10, 1.1 c}], Text["c", {1, 1, 1.8 c}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting an error: The specified setting for the option Graphics3DBoxOptions, BoxRatios cannot be used. I'm using version 11.

Comment: I am using 13.3. But you can simply delete this option and the plot will be scaled differently.