# How to draw an arrow upto to the length of the axis of an ellipsoid?

Tags: plotting

This is a follow-up question to one of my previous questions. How can I restrict `Arrow`  (coming from the center `c`) till the length of `a` on the ellipse in the x-direction?

```
a=12.4786;
b=33.3395;
c=21.0691;
e1=Ellipsoid[{0,0,c},{a,b,c}];
c1=RegionCentroid[e1];
axes=Graphics3D[{Red,Arrow[Tube[{c1,a UnitVector[3,1]}]]}];
g3=SliceContourPlot3D[x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2+(z-c)^2/c^2,{x,y,z}\[Element]e1,ContourShading->{Opacity[0.4,White]}];
Show[g3,Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.2],e1}],axes,AxesLabel->{X,Y,Z}]
```

Link to the previous question: [How to draw axes inside an ellipsoid](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/288710/how-to-draw-axes-inside-an-ellipsoid)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Arrow[Tube[{c1, c1 + a UnitVector[3, 1]}]]
```

Comment: Now I get it! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

For the complete axes

```
$Version

(* "13.3.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

a = 12.4786;
b = 33.3395;
c = 21.0691;
e1 = Ellipsoid[{0, 0, c}, {a, b, c}];
c1 = RegionCentroid[e1];

g3 = Show[
  SliceContourPlot3D[
   x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 + (z - c)^2/c^2, {x, y, z} \[Element] e1,
   ContourShading -> {Opacity[0.4, White]}],
  Graphics3D[{#[[1]], 
      Arrow[Tube[{c1, c1 + #[[2]] UnitVector[3, #[[3]]]}]]} & /@
    Transpose[{{Red, Blue, Green}, {a, b, c}, {1, 2, 3}}]],
  BoxRatios -> Automatic]
```

[image]